# Adding bluetooth feature to my OS Bluetooth Feature

Tags: c++, nasm

i m developing my own os, i 've reached a stage where i want to my os to communicate with other hardwares that uses bluetooth.

So the the challange is i ve been searching for the bluetooth programing documentation , but i cant find it. Is there any library somewhere on internet to download, which platform independed or a documentation instead.

I m using Lenovo T44op built in bluetooth

Comment: I doubt it. This is not standard. You could try to understand how the Linux driver for your laptop's Bluetooth chip works.

Comment: Keep in mind that when writing an operating system, generally you are controlling hardware - i.e. actual chips on your computer's motherboard. Sometimes there is a standard way to control certain types of hardware. Sometimes, there is not.

Comment: Thanx user253751, i will mark it as a first clue to my research